# How do i get rotation of wall using revit api?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

If an Element is family instance then:

```
(FamilyInstance.Location as LocationPoint).Rotation;
```

I can easily get a rotation easily for family instance.

If I try for wall

```
Curve curve = ((Wall).Location as LocationCurve).Curve;
```

Or anything like that.

For example :

1. In preceding image,
   trying to rotate wall to 90 Degree.
   [image: normal wall]
2. In below Image,
   after rotating 90 Degree
   [image: wall after rotation]

**Need to get the rotated angle of the wall.**

Comment: So.. what are you trying to do? This seems like a very unclear question. From the title, I can assume. From your code, there is no description of much else. Please elaborate quite a bit more.

Comment: I placed a wall in Revit project and rotate wall by 90 degree, now i need to get the rotation  angle of wall.

Comment: @Symon , can you please have a look at the issue again, I have modified with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wall curve is a straight line, you can just grab the angle from the line: let V be the vector from the wall curve start to end point, and determine its angle to the X axis: angle = `V.AngleTo(XYZ.BasisX)`.